# turning two string values into numbers, set to a fixed value, and performing a mathematical operation on them without float errors

Tags: javascript

I'm [making a calculator](http://codepen.io/S-Lynne/pen/BogJPr?editors=001) using Javascript. I've set it up to create arrays for the numbers entered, how many decimal places each has, and the operators used like this:

```
var num_memory = ['1.1','2','14.55'];
var dec_test = [1,0,2];
var fun_memory = ['add','multiply'];
```

Then when the user hits equals the button, the answer is calculated according to the following:

```
for (i=0; i<fun_memory.length; i++) {
  switch (fun_memory[i]) {
    case 'add':
      answer = num_memory[0] + num_memory[1]
      break;
    case 'subtract':
      answer = num_memory[0] - num_memory[1]
      break;
    case 'multiply':
      answer = num_memory[0]*num_memory[1]
      break;
    case 'divide':
      answer = num_memory[0]/num_memory[1]
      break;
  }
  num_memory.shift();
  num_memory[0]=answer;
}
```

The problem is that because num_memory values have to be stored as strings, I get floating point errors. I need something like

```
parseFloat(num_memory[0]).toFixed(dec_test)
```

but that returns a string. I've thought about using toFixed() on the answer, but that won't work for multiplication or division.

Is there anyway to just return two numbers with decimals fixed to specific values and perform an operation on them?

Comment: “I've thought about using toFixed() on the answer, but that won't work for multiplication or division.” Why not?

Comment: @RyanO'Hara because the decimal points after 0.2*0.2 = 0.04 would have two places after the decimal, but 0.2*0.5 = 0.1 would only have one. With addition and subtraction you always know how many decimal places you're going to have, but not with multiplication and division.

Comment: I dont get the reason why you storing teh decimal location.
I mean you could have doe like this answer = parseFloat(num_memory[0]) + parseFloat(num_memory[1])

Comment: @Cyril That gives a floating point error. I was trying to store the decimal to use toFixed() before I realized that toFixed() returns a string.

Comment: So you want significant figures instead of decimal places? `(0.2).toPrecision(2) === "0.20"`, `(0.04).toPrecision(2) === "0.040"`. Note that it’ll give `"2e+1"` for `(20).toPrecision(2)`, so you might want to expand that to zeroes if it’s small enough.

Comment: @Cyril for example if I have num_memory=[0.2,0.95] and fun_memory=['subtract'] and I use parseFloat(num_memory[0]) - parseFloat(num_memory[1]), then I get 0.10500000000000001 instead of 0.105

Comment: @RyanO'Hara I still would need to have prior knowledge of how many decimal places my operation would return if I used toPrecision(). If I pick too few, then I will be rounding when I shouldn't be and if I pick too many, I will have trailing zeroes.

Comment: Use `toFixed(12)` and remove trailing zeroes, then.

Answer (score 0):

I see this kind of questions regularly and I'm not even here for a very long time, but I ask myself every time I see such a question: why don't they just use fractions? It's not even that complicated, here's a quick (and dirty!) hack:

```
function Rational(a,b){
  this.num = a || 0;
  this.den = b || 1; // 0 = 0/1
}

Number.prototype.sign = function(){
  return (this < 0)?-1:1;
};

Rational.prototype.add = function(rat){
  var ret,gcd,a,b,c,d;

  a = this.num; c = rat.num;
  b = this.den; d = rat.den;

  if(a == 0)return rat;
  if(c == 0)return this;

  ret = new Rational();
  gcd = b.gcd(d);
  ret.den = Math.max(b,d)/gcd*Math.min(b,d);
  ret.num = (a * d)/gcd + (c * b)/gcd;
  if(ret.num == 0){
     ret.den = 1;
  }
  return ret;
};
Rational.prototype.sub = function(rat){
  var ret;
  if( rat.num == 0 ){
    ret = new Rational();
    ret.num = rat.num * (-1);
    ret.den = rat.den;
  }
  if(this.num == 0){
    ret = this;
    ret.den = 1;
    return ret;
  }

  this.num *= -1;
  ret = this.add(rat);
  this.num *= -1;
  ret.num  *= -1;

  return ret;
};

Rational.prototype.mul = function(rat){
  var ret = new Rational();
  var gcd_ad, gcd_bc;
  var a = this.num;  var c = rat.num;
  var b = this.den;var d = rat.den;
  if( a == 0 ||  c == 0 ){
    ret.num = 0;
    return ret;
  }
  // avoids some early overflows
  gcd_ad = a.gcd(d);
  gcd_bc = b.gcd(c);
  if(gcd_ad != 1){
    a = a/gcd_ad;
    d = d/gcd_ad;
  }
  if(gcd_bc != 1){
    b = b/gcd_bc;
    c = c/gcd_bc;
  }  

  ret.num = a * c;
  ret.den = b * d;

  return ret;
};

Rational.prototype.inv = function(){
  var ret = new Rational(this.den * this.num.sign(),
                         Math.abs(this.num));
  return ret;
};

Rational.prototype.div = function(rat){
  var ret, temp;

  if(this.num == 0){
    return (new Rational());
  }
  if(rat.num == 0){
    return undefined;
  }
  return this.mul(rat.inv());
};

Rational.prototype.reduce = function(){
  var ret, gcd;
  if(this.num == 0){
    return (new Rational());
  }
  if(this.den == 0){
    return undefined;
  }
  ret = new Rational();
  gcd = this.den.gcd(this.num);
  ret.num = this.num/gcd;
  ret.den = this.den/gcd;
  return ret;
};

Rational.prototype.toString = function(){
 return this.num.toString() + "/" + this.den.toString(); 
};
//Yes, I know ;-)
Number.BINT_MAX = ((1<<30)|((1<<30)-1));
Number.prototype.gcd = function(n){
  var x,y,g,temp;
  if(this > n){
    return n.gcd(this);
  }
  x = Math.abs(this);
  y = Math.abs(n);
  g = 1;
  if(   x > Number.BINT_MAX
     || y > Number.BINT_MAX){
    while(x.isEven() && y.isEven()){
      x = Math.floor(x/2);
      y = Math.floor(y/2);
      g = Math.floor(g*2);
    }
    while(x != 0){
      while(x.isEven())x = Math.floor(x/2);
      while(y.isEven())y = Math.floor(y/2);
      temp =   Math.floor(Math.abs(x-y)/2);
      if(x>=y)x = temp;
      else y = temp;
    }
    return (g*y);    
  }
  else{
    while(!(x&1) && !(y&1)){
      x = x>>1;y = y>>1;
          g = g<<1;
    }
    while(x != 0){
      while(!(x&1))x >>= 1;
      while(!(y&1))y >>= 1;
      temp =   Math.abs(x-y)>>1;
      if(x>=y)x = temp;
      else y = temp;
    }
    return (g*y);
  }
};

var a = new Rational(123,234)
var b = new Rational(12,22)
a.add(b).reduce().toString()
```